# VS C++ LoadLibrary always returns null

Tags: c++, qt, dll, visual-studio-2015, loadlibrary

VS2015 mfc project.
Trying to load QT5Widgets.dll

```
CString sPath("M:\\ParseDLL\\Qt5Widgets.dll");
HMODULE hm = LoadLibrary(sPath);
```

hm is always null. I tried to change character set (unicode, multy bite), use _T, L before path text, changed win 32 to 64. Still nothing. GetlastErorr code 126 tells "The specified module could not be found". Dll is on this path. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you inspect the DLL using the dependency viewer? Perhaps that DLL depends on another one that can't be loaded.

Comment: Dependency Viewer can also profile running applications and troubleshoot `LoadLibrary` calls as they happen.

Comment: @void: You may want to read the whole question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tt looks like a missing DLL.
If `M:\ParseDLL\Qt5Widgets.dll` does exist, it means you are missing one of the DLL required by Qt5Widgets (or a DLL required by a DLL required by Qt5Widgets and so on).

Like said by @Bathsheba, using a dependancy viewer tool can help you find the guilty DLL.

Quick checklist

- you need to have in the same folder (or in your PATH) at least Qt5Core.dll and Qt5Gui.dll and make sure
- use the same compiler (version and architecture) for your software than the one used to build Qt
- you might also want to use the debug versions of Qt DLLs (Qt5Widgetsd.dll, etc.) if you are building your soft in debug.